# Can a tagfield in ExtJS 5 use a bufferedstore?

Tags: extjs, combobox, store, extjs5, buffered

I am trying to create a tag field. I have it displayed without any problems. I am just trying to use a bufferedstore instead of a memory paging store. Is this possible in a tagfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this makes any sense, but according to Sencha's support team the answer is **[no](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303639-Combo-with-a-buffered-store-does-not-work-(store.setExtraKeys-is-not-a-function)&p=1110102&viewfull=1#post1110102)**:

> The buffered store really only works with the Grid component.

Comment: Yeah I saw that too but I was trying to see if there was some way that I could use it. It would be helpful because I could avoid paging, which can be difficult to get to work exactly as you want.